# Omniauth configuration in secrets rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, configuration, omniauth-facebook

I'm trying to configure different environments so I can test Facebook login.  Production works fine, but I'm having trouble with the correct way to include my development credentials.  I'm trying to use secrets.yml since that is what I've used to store other api credentials.

Here's what I've got in the initializer, omniauth.rb :

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'],
           :scope => 'email,user_location'
 end
```

And this in my secrets.yml file:

```
development:
  FACEBOOK_APP_ID: mytestappid
  FACEBOOK_SECRET: mytestsecretkey

production:
  FACEBOOK_APP_ID: <%= ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_ID"] %>
  FACEBOOK_SECRET: <%= ENV["FACEBOOK_SECRET"] %>
```

I tried changing the 'config' to 'secrets' in the initializer but that didn't work.  I suspect it has something to do with middleware but I'm not sure. Can anyone help point me in the direction of configuring this properly?  Production only works bc I set the config variables with heroku.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: it really worked with my answer? Without changing anything? Its weird when things works at the first try.

Comment: Hi Daniel-  It removed the error I was getting for not having the app ID, although now I'm getting another error, but I don't think it's related to your answer.  If it turns out it is related, I will edit your answer.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't reading the secrets file. Change your omniauth.rb to this:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, Rails.application.secrets.FACEBOOK_APP_ID, Rails.application.secrets.FACEBOOK_SECRET,
           :scope => 'email,user_location'
end
```

***PS:*** its necessary to restart the server after the changes